# Beginner at Python: How to fix problem of getting '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting this error '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'from this part of my code while user_choice_of_questions > number_of_questions_answered, line 149 I was wondering if anyone could help me or find a solution as I am very stuck or if there was another method of looping this game. If anyone could help it would be much apretiacted.When you press "" and after the User chooses the Game Mode 1. Addition It should ask the User a Continuous number of questions but this does not happen and an error appears.

Thank You

```
#Round looping component version 1
#The Round Looping component does not work as intended
#The problem is that if the User wants to quit the game (exit code 'xxx') and
#They press <ENTER> to play the game again,
#The round heading (the number of questions the User answered) does not reset

#The import random is used for the random integer between the specified ranges
import random

#Functions

#Function to check how many questions the User wants to play
#User has a choice of how many questions they want to answer or they can choose the
#Continous question option
def check_how_many_questions(question):
    while True:
        #The User will input a response to the given question
        response = input(question)

        #Error message
        how_many_questions_error = "Please input either an integer that is more than 0 or <ENTER>."
        #If ifinite mode is not chosen, check response is an integer more than 0
        if response != "":
            try:
                response = int(response)

                #If response is too low, go back to the start of the loop and display an error message to help user
                if response < 1:
                    print(how_many_questions_error)
                    continue

            #If the User inputs an invalid value, Error message is displayed
            except ValueError:
                print(how_many_questions_error)
                continue

        return response

#Function to check what Game Mode the User wants to play
def game_mode_input_checker(question):
    while True:

        #Error message
        error_message = "Error please input an Integer between 1 and 4 (1. Addition 2. Subtraction 3. Multiplication 4. Division)"

        try:
            #It is an float input in the case the User inpurs a valid input but just with a .0
            response = float(input(question))

            #If User's response is 1 (Addition) return the response
            if response == 1:
                return response

            #If User's response is not 1,2,3,4 print the ERROR message
            else:
                print(error_message)
                print()
                continue

        #If the User inputs an invalid value print the ERROR message
        except ValueError:
            print(error_message)
            print()

#Function to check the User's input
#In this instance this function is used to check if the User's input for the Mathematical questions is valid
def input_checker(question):
    while True:
        try:
            #The User will input a response to the given question
            #It is an float input in the case the User inputs a calid input but just with a .0
            response = float(input(question))
            return response
        # Error message will be printed out to the User
        except ValueError:
            print("<ERROR> Please enter an Integer\n")
            continue

#Continue the game function
#This functions purpose is to ask the User after each question or if they quit playing the game if they wish to continue or quit playing the game, 'xxx'
def continue_game(question):
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        #The User will input a response to the given question
        #.lower() is used in the case the User types the correct input but with the wrong casing
        response = input(question).lower()

        if response == "":
            return response

        elif response == "xxx":
            return response

        #If response is not "" or 'xxx' Error message will display to the User
        else:
            print()
            print("<Error> please enter either <Enter> or 'xxx'")
            print()

#Statement generator
#Decorates the statements in the Lucky Unicorn game
def statement_generator(statement, decoration):

    #The of the statement is the chosen decoration times by 3
    sides = decoration * 3

    #The statement outputed to the User is the chosen statement with
    #the sides on the left and right of the statement
    statement = "{} {} {}".format(sides, statement, sides)
    #The decotration on the top and bottom of the the statement is
    #the chosen decoration and it is the length of the statement
    top_bottom = decoration * len(statement)

    #top_bottom and statement variables are outputed to the User
    print(top_bottom)
    print(statement)
    print(top_bottom)

    return ""

#Main routine goes here

#Questions answered correct
questions_answered_correct = 0

#Questions answered incorrect
questions_answered_incorrect = 0

#Number of question answered
number_of_questions_answered = 0

#Game loop
game_loop = ""
while game_loop == "":

    #Ask the User how many questions they want to answer if they want to play the
    #option where they can choose how many questions they want
    #to answer of if they want to play the continuous question option
    user_choice_of_questions = check_how_many_questions("There are two options you can choose from for how many question you can answer.\n"
                                                        "The first is where you choose how many question you want to answer.\n"
                                                        "To choose this option just simply input an integer value.\n"
                                                        "The second option is where a continuous number of questions are asked to you.\n"
                                                        "TO choose the second option press <ENTER>\n"
                                                        "\nHow many questions do you want to answer: ")

    #Asks the User what game mode they want to play (1. Addition 2. Subtraction 3. Multiplication 4. Division)
    game_mode = game_mode_input_checker("What game mode do you want to play (1. Addition)? ")

    while user_choice_of_questions > number_of_questions_answered:

        #If the User's Choice is <ENTER> the User has decided to answer the Continuous Question's option
        if user_choice_of_questions == "":
            heading = "Continuous Question: Question {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1)

        #If the User's Choice is not <ENTER> the User has decided to play the User Question number choose option
        else:
            heading = "Question {} of {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, user_choice_of_questions)

        #Game Mode 1. Addition
        if game_mode == 1:

            #Displays to the User the Question Number
            statement_generator(heading, "#")

            #Number 1 that is in the first position before
            #The addition is a random integer between 0 and 20
            number_1 = random.randint(0,20)
            #Number 2 that is in the first position before
            #The addition is a random integer between 0 and 20
            number_2 = random.randint(0,20)
            #The answer is equal to Number 1 + Number 2
            answer = number_1 + number_2

            #The question asked to the User
            #The Input Checker is a float input in the case the User input the correct answer but just with a .0
            response = input_checker("What is {} + {}?  ".format(number_1, number_2))

            #If the User's response is equal to the answer (Number 1 + Number 2) the User gets the question 'Correct'
            #The number of questions answered increases by 1
            #The number of qestions answered correct increases by 1
            if response == answer:
                result = "Correct"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_correct += 1


            #If the User's response is not equal to the answer (Number 1 + Number 2) the User gets the question 'Incorrect'
            #The number of questions answered increases by 1
            #The number of qestions answered correct increases by 1
            else:
                result = "Incorrect"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_incorrect += 1

            #The question outcome of question is outputed to the User
            print(question_outcome)

            #End game if the number of rounds has been played
            #The number of questions answered is reset back to 0
            if number_of_questions_answered == user_choice_of_questions:
                number_of_questions_answered = 0
                break

            #If the number of rounds played is more than or equal to
            #One the User will be asked if they wish to continue the game or if they wish to
            #Quit the game they should input 'xxx'
            if number_of_questions_answered >= 1:
                print()
                game_loop = continue_game("Press <Enter> if you wish to continue the game, if you wish to quit type 'xxx': ")
                print()

            #If the User inputs 'xxx' when they are asked if they want to continue the game or not
            #The Game Loop will end
            if game_loop == "xxx":
                break

    #The User will be asked if they wish to play the game again (<ENTER>) or if they wish to not
    #play the game again ('xxx')
    game_loop = continue_game("If you wish to play the game again press <ENTER>, if you do not want to play the game again type 'xxx': ")
    print()

#Thanks the User for playing the game
print("Thank You for playing the Quiz Quest Game")
```

Comment: There is no need to post this much code. Please see [ask] and provide a [mre]

Comment: I would like to point out that line 162 is a comment, it should be line 149.
Also, the line of code is `while user_choice_of_questions > number_of_questions_answered` instead of `while number_of_questions_answered < user_choice_of_questions` which you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please post the full traceback error.

Answer (score 0):

`user_choice_of_questions` comes from function `check_how_many_questions`, after investigating your function.

```py
def check_how_many_questions(question):
    while True:
        #The User will input a response to the given question
        response = input(question)

        #Error message
        how_many_questions_error = "Please input either an integer that is more than 0 or <ENTER>."
        #If ifinite mode is not chosen, check response is an integer more than 0
        if response != "":
            try:
                response = int(response)

                #If response is too low, go back to the start of the loop and display an error message to help user
                if response < 1:
                    print(how_many_questions_error)
                    continue

            #If the User inputs an invalid value, Error message is displayed
            except ValueError:
                print(how_many_questions_error)
                continue

        return response
```

If you entered an empty string to the function, it will simply return an empty **string** which will cause the error you mentioned. Please perform some handling for empty string, for example

```py
DEFAULT_VALUE = 5

response = input(question)
if response != "":
   # do your work to turn the value into integer or perform error handling
else:
   return DEFAULT_VALUE
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates. (We get an instance of this question probably several times a day).

Comment: ...to provide help center documentation re: the above -- in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".